# Can't get library jar to work with Android and Proguard

Tags: android, proguard, flurry

I have an Android library project (A) and the Android application (B), in Eclipse. For this setup I am using Proguard, so far without a problem. Now I want to add the Flurry library (.jar) to my library project, which in debug mode on the emulator works fine.

However, when I want to export the final and signed apk of my application, using Proguard, I get many "can't find referenced class ..." warnings and the apk can't be created.

Some of these classes are:

```
org.joda.time.LocalDateTime  
org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
com.jumptap.adtag.JtAdView
...
```

Ok, so I added the following to the proguard.cfg file:

```
...
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-libraryjars ../libproj/libs/FlurryAgent.jar
...
-keep public class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent { *; }
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.avro.** { *; }
-keep interface com.flurry.** { *; }
-keep public class org.joda.time.** { public protected *; }
...
```

However, I still get the sam errors :(
Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: I get issues building with Proguard if I have automatic build on.  I have to switch it off for a release build.  May not be related but worth trying...

Comment: Well, I ended up with replacing Flurry with Google Analytics -- much smaller JAR file and no problems at all with Proguard :)

Comment: Thanks Ifor! After adding google player services as a library project I have been fighting with non-repeatable build failures when exporting Proguard from Eclipse. The fix: turn off automatic build; clean all projects; build google-play-services_lib (right-click -> Build Project), then Export... main project via usual flow for signed proguard build. Before I turned off auto build I had many weird errors -- missing class errors, incomplete mapping.txt, bad builds with no console errors (!) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the flurry jar has optional references to some other libraries (joda-time, snappy, ...).

Adding `-keep` options for the missing references does not help at all as it would only keep the specified classes, but they are missing. Instead you should add appropriate `-dontwarn` directives:

```
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
```

should ignore any warnings originating from flurry classes.